# Как правильно экранировать символ $ в переменных окружения в Docker

Tags: docker, экранирование, environment-variables

в gitlab-ci записываются переменные окружения для контейнера, среди них переменная со значением вида
`DB_PASS = SDD$qerwt@dbhost:0000/dbpath`

но в контейнере часть после знака $ исчезает, видимо превращается в переменную со значением null, то есть переменная в итоге выглядит вот так

```
DB_PASS = SDD@dbhost:0000/dbpath
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно записать эту строку, чтобы она отобразилась корректно. Пробовала в разных кавычках, через символ \

Comment: Два раза символ доллара написать?

Comment: вероятно, надо двойные кавычки применить там, где эта переменная используется.